# Eclipse keyboard shortcuts broken in OSX 10.5.6

Tags: eclipse, macos, osx-leopard, dvorak

So I have been using Leopard for a year now, and the lastest update broke the keyboard mapping for eclipse.  I use the dvorak layout, and now in eclipse if I press the ⌘ and the b key it does a build, instead of a cut(b = x).

Does anyone else have this issue, and are there any workarounds?

**EDIT:** The best current workaround is to upgrade to 10.5.7.

Comment: Stack Overflow - where programmers go to learn that their OS needs updating.

Currently in the process of updating, I'll let you know if I'm affected either way.

Comment: In this case it would be that your OS needs 'not' updating, since the problem did not exist in 10.5.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woo-hoo!  It's fixed as of 10.5.7!

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same thing, using Eclipse 3.3.2. My workaround has been to go in to Eclipse->Preferences->General->Keys and manually re-map the assignments for the keyboard commands I use most frequently.

Comment: This has worked for me too in Eclipse. I had to edit these prefs to setup HOME and END keys anyway (line end, line start, when 'editing text').  Remember to export your preferences because they won't stick when when you switch workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse 3.4.1, standard (US) qwerty layout. I haven't found any shortcut problems, I temporarily set B to do cut (by fiddling with the key assignments in the eclipse preferences), and that worked OK.

Comment: Did you make sure it was cleared from the other one when you remapped it?

Comment: When i pressed the key, the worng value appeared, so remapping will not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue, except not all the key bindings are broken. Command + S still saves, for example. But most of the commands evaluate as though I'm using QWERTY. I haven't found any solution so far except to manually remap the keys which I haven't done because its a huge pain.

Comment: I think the the os framework maps Command + S and Command + Q to the correct items.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.  A supporting symptom: when I tried to "fix" it by
using Preferences->General->Keys to remap "Undo" from F9 to Command-Z,
when I typed Command-Z, it echoed as Command-/.  / is the non-Dvorak
key that sits in the same keyboard position as the Dvorak Z.  So Eclipse
is somehow getting at keys "before" the Dvorak mapping is applied by
the OS.

I agree that it makes Eclipse unuseable.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an eclipse only problem, because the same problem does not affect me when I use my Dvorak layout and other java tools such as JDeveloper or SQLDeveloper.

It drives me nuts, and I find myself actually booting windows or linux in a virtual machine so that I can use Eclipse with semi-coherent key mappings.

The odd thing is, though, that this problem did not exist to start with for me.  The key mappings used to work fine in Dvorak.  Then one day, poof.

I wonder if it had anything to do with the fact that non-Dvorak users on my machine change the key mapping back to qwerty.

I should mention, though I don't know if it is/isn't relevant, but I am using the CFEclipse plugin.  I have not tried to invoke this behaviour with other perspectives yet.

Maybe for fun, I will try creating another local account and see if I can use eclipse to start with.

Another possibility could be the VM itself, and the way it handles the underlying keyboard interception.

Any other thoughts?

Allen

Comment: I believe it is a Carbon problem.  The Cocoa version of eclipse works, and other Cocoa apps have reported problems.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in the 10.5.7 update.